# convert sql to hql

Tags: java, sql, database, hql

I am performing this via sql but i want to do this in  hql, select statement in from ( select count(*)...) not works in hql, any sugestion and optimization would be appreciated

```
SELECT u.username,u.device_tocken,sr.count
from users u,
    (select count(*) as count ,ssr.recepient as res from survey_recipient ssr where      
    (ssr.is_read is false and ssr.recepient in ('abc','xyz'))group by ssr.recepient ) sr 
where 
    (u.username = sr.res and u.device_tocken is not null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate does not support subselects in from clouse. 
i tried many things and gave up when i found this jira issue.

see here https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-3356

**But if you have to use subselect you can create database views and use them in your sql as normal tables.**